# Create menu with foreach loop and array php

Tags: php

for my site i need to create the menu with a array and print it out with a foreach loop.

This is the array i already have:

```
$aMenu = array(
 'Home' => 'index.php',
 'Over mij' => 'overmij.php',
 'Contact' => 'contact.php'
 ');
```

So i need to print this array in a foreach loop this is what i need to print out:

```
<li><a href="index.php" title="menuitems" class="current">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="overmij.php" title="menuitems" >Over mij</a></li
 <li><a href="contact.php" title="menuitems" >Contact</a></li>
```

I also have to get the class 'current' on the page i am currently at.

I havent worked yet with a foreach loop, and i cant find it on internet. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Here you can find answer => http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

You can print menu like this:

```
    <?php

    $aMenu = array(
     'Home' => 'index.php',
     'Over mij' => 'overmij.php',
     'Contact' => 'contact.php'
    );

    $list = "<ul>";
    foreach($aMenu as $key=>$menu) {
       $class = '';
       if($current_page == $key) { $class = 'active'; }
       $list = $list.'<li><a href="'.$menu.'" class="'.$class.'" title="menuitems" >'.$key.'</a></li>';
    }
    $list .= "</ul>";
    echo $list;

?>
```

Comment: Forgot about <ul></ul> and current page

Comment: @JayeshChitroda thank you very much! But the only thing i need now is that i have to get the class current on the page that i am currently on.

Comment: Set $current_page and store current page name into it, so that you can check whether active class should be added or not.

Comment: `$list = $list` it's  the same has `$list .=`

Comment: $list .= means $list = $list."..."

Comment: @JayeshChitroda i am not allowed to paste the codes to the 3 pages so i cant set currentpage.

Comment: No I mean you just to set $current_page value while page load, then in header file it will already get that $current page - check condition and accordingly add active class

Comment: @JayeshChitroda I did put $current_page; in the head of head.php but now im getting this error message:
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: current_page in C:\Users\Jari R\Desktop\portfolio-template-master\portfolio-template-master\includes\functies.php on line 16

Comment: set $current_page before your header load

Answer (score 0):

```
$aMenu = array(
 'Home' => 'index.php',
 'Over mij' => 'overmij.php',
 'Contact' => 'contact.php'
 );

<?php if(isset($aMenu)):?>
<ul class="menu">
  <?php foreach($aMenu as $name => $page):?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $page;?>" title="<?php echo $name;?>"><?php echo $name;?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The 'current selected' function is implemented via Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can looking for current requested script file with
`basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])`

This snippet is looking for server's requested script name, such as (at bold)

> http://example.com/**index.php**

And validate it with your defined array value

```
if (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME') == $filename) {
   //add class
   $current = 'current';
}
```

In the end using ternary operator to make it shorter

```
foreach ( $aMenu as $menu => $filename ) {
   $current = (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) == $filename) ? 'current' : '';
   echo '<li><a href="'.$filename.'" title="menuitems" class="'.$current.'">'.$menu.'</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` and `if` to achieve your desired output.

```
<?php 
$aMenu = array(
    'Home' => 'index.php',
    'Over mij' => 'overmij.php',
    'Contact' => 'contact.php'
);?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($aMenu as $key => $val){ 
$active = ($page == $key) ? 'current' : '';
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $key?>" title="menuitems" class="<?php echo $active;?>"><?php echo $val;?></a></li>
}
?>
</ul>
```

In `index.php` page you need to use `$page = 'index.php'` and so on...

> Note: You need to set the `$page` in every page like the page name. There are lots of way to do that. This is only one.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but try code below
You can change `$current_page` to the value and it will set to current:

```
<?php    
     $aMenu = array(
          'Home' => 'index.php',
          'Over mij' => 'overmij.php',
          'Contact' => 'contact.php'
     );

     $current_page = 'overmij.php';
?>

<li>
    <?php foreach ($aMenu as $key => $value) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $value; ?>" title="menuitems" <?php if($current_page == $value){echo "class='current'";}?>><?php echo $key;?></a>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</li>
```

Comment: Thankyou, but i have the code in functions.php so i cant do $current_page because i am not allowed to paste the code into the 3 pages. Can you help me?

Comment: can you post the function so I could check please??